# Incompatible Types found java.lang.string but expected int

Tags: java, string, types, bluej

I have a wierd problem. I created some code at home and it compiled perfectly, no errors. Now I try compiling the same code at school and im getting the incompatible types error for string d :S Im using blue J by the way.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
/** 
* @author (Andrew Napier, Sikander Singh) 
* @version (December 18th, 2012)
*/
public class MonthlyData extends JFrame
{
private JLabel title, stitle, l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11,l12,l13,l14;
private JLabel Usage,Estimated,solu1,solu2,total2;
private JLabel l15,l16,l17,l18,l19,l20,l21,l22,l23,l24,l25,l26,l27,l28,l29;
private JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5, panel6, panel7;
String[] deviceStrings = { "Device", "Blackberry", "Other", "Internetstick"};
String[] date = { "Day", "Week", "Month"};
public double email2 = 0;
public double email1;
public double web2 = 0;
public double IM2 = 0;
public double video2 = 0;
public double song2 = 0;
public double app2 = 0;
static final int email50 = 50;
static final int email100 = 100;
static final int email150 = 150;
static final int email200 = 200;
static final int email250 = 250;
static final int email300 = 300;
public JSlider Email = new JSlider(0,300,0);
public JSlider Web = new JSlider(0,500,0);
public JSlider IM = new JSlider(0,500,0);
public JSlider Video = new JSlider(0,300,0);
public JSlider Song = new JSlider(0,200,0);
public  JSlider App_G = new JSlider(0,100,0);
public String currentdate;


public double emailvalue, webvalue,IMvalue, videovalue, songvalue, appvalue;    
public double webmb, immb, videomb, songmb,appmb,emailmb;

public MonthlyData ()
{
    super ("MonthlyData");
    setSize (1000,1100);


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////// panel1
    panel1 = new JPanel ();                                              
    panel1.setLayout (new GridLayout(1,1));
    panel1.setVisible(true);
    panel1.setBackground (Color.black);
    title = new JLabel ("            WANNA KNOW HOW MUCH DATA YOU NEED?",JLabel.LEFT);
    title.setForeground(Color.white);
    title.setFont (new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,25));
    l1 = new JLabel ("");
    l2 = new JLabel ("");
    /////////////////////////////////////////////// panel2   
    panel2 = new JPanel ();                                             
    panel2.setLayout (new GridLayout(1,1));
    panel2.setVisible(true);
    panel2.setBackground (Color.gray);
    stitle = new JLabel ("PICK A PHONE OR INTERNET STICK AND THEN DRAG .",JLabel.LEFT);
    stitle.setForeground(Color.black);
    stitle.setFont (new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,14));
    //////////////////////////////////////////////// panel3
    panel3 = new JPanel ();                                              
    panel3.setLayout (new FlowLayout());
    panel3.setVisible(true);
    panel3.setBackground (Color.white);
    l3 = new JLabel ("Select Your Device:",JLabel.RIGHT);
    l3.setForeground(Color.red);


    l4 = new JLabel ("Tell us how much of what's listed here you think you'll use:");
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////// panel4


    panel4 = new JPanel ();                                               
    panel4.setLayout (new GridLayout(6,7));
    panel4.setVisible(true);
    panel4.setBackground (Color.white);
    l5 = new JLabel ("Email");
    l6 = new JLabel ("WebPage");
    l7 = new JLabel ("Instant Message");
    l8 = new JLabel ("Streaming Video");
    l9 = new JLabel ("Song");
    l10 = new JLabel ("Application or Game");


    l11 = new JLabel (""+" Emails");


    l12 = new JLabel (" MB");
    l15 = new JLabel (" MB");
    l18 = new JLabel (" MB");
    l21 = new JLabel (" MB");
    l24 = new JLabel (" MB");
    l27 = new JLabel (" MB");



    final JComboBox devicelist = new JComboBox (deviceStrings);
    devicelist.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                **String d = (String) devicelist.getSelectedItem();**


                switch (d) {//check for a match
                    case "Blackberry":
                    emailmb = 0.002;
                    webmb = 0.07;
                    immb = 0.005;
                    videomb = 1;
                    songmb = 4;
                    appmb = 0.44;
                    l12.setText(emailmb + " MB");
                    l15.setText(webmb + " MB");
                    l18.setText(immb + " MB");
                    l21.setText(videomb + " MB");
                    l24.setText(songmb + " MB");
                    l27.setText(appmb + " MB");
                    break;
                    case "Other":
                    emailmb = 0.02;
                    webmb = 0.17;
                    immb = 0.03;
                    videomb = 1;
                    songmb = 4;
                    appmb = 4;
                    l12.setText(emailmb + " MB");
                    l15.setText(webmb + " MB");
                    l18.setText(immb + " MB");
                    l21.setText(videomb + " MB");
                    l24.setText(songmb + " MB");
                    l27.setText(appmb + " MB");
                    break;
                    case "Internetstick":
                    emailmb = 0.04;
                    webmb = 0.2;
                    immb = 0.002;
                    videomb = 4;
                    songmb = 5;
                    appmb = 30;
                    l12.setText(emailmb + " MB");
                    l15.setText(webmb + " MB");
                    l18.setText(immb + " MB");
                    l21.setText(videomb + " MB");
                    l24.setText(songmb + " MB");
                    l27.setText(appmb + " MB");
                    break;


                }


            }
        });
    devicelist.setSelectedItem(devicelist[0]);




    final JComboBox date1 = new JComboBox (date);
    date1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                String s = (String) date1.getSelectedItem();//get the selected item


                switch (s) {//check for a match
                    case "Day":
                    emailvalue = 30;


                    break;
                    case "Week":
                    emailvalue = 4;


                    break;
                    case "Month":
                    emailvalue = 1;


                    break;


                }


            }
        });
    date1.setSelectedItem(date[0]);


    final JComboBox date2 = new JComboBox (date); 
    date2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                String s2 = (String) date2.getSelectedItem();//get the selected item


                switch (s2) {//check for a match
                    case "Day":
                    webvalue = 30;


                    break;
                    case "Week":
                    webvalue = 4;


                    break;
                    case "Month":
                    webvalue = 1;


                    break;


                }


            }
        });
    date2.setSelectedItem(date[0]);


    final JComboBox date3 = new JComboBox (date);


    date3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                String s3 = (String) date3.getSelectedItem();//get the selected item


                switch (s3) {//check for a match
                    case "Day":
                    IMvalue = 30;


                    break;
                    case "Week":
                    IMvalue = 4;


                    break;
                    case "Month":
                    IMvalue = 1;


                    break;


                }


            }
        });
    date3.setSelectedItem(date[0]);


    final JComboBox date4 = new JComboBox (date);
    date4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                String s4 = (String) date4.getSelectedItem();//get the selected item


                switch (s4) {//check for a match
                    case "Day":
                    videovalue = 30;


                    break;
                    case "Week":
                    videovalue = 4;


                    break;
                    case "Month":
                    videovalue = 1;


                    break;


                }


            }
        });
    date4.setSelectedItem(date[0]);


    final JComboBox date5 = new JComboBox (date);
    date5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                String s5 = (String) date5.getSelectedItem();//get the selected item


                switch (s5) {//check for a match
                    case "Day":
                    songvalue = 30;


                    break;
                    case "Week":
                    songvalue = 4;


                    break;
                    case "Month":
                    songvalue = 1;


                    break;


                }


            }
        });
    date5.setSelectedItem(date[0]);


    final JComboBox date6 = new JComboBox (date);
    date6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                String s6 = (String) date6.getSelectedItem();//get the selected item


                switch (s6) {//check for a match
                    case "Day":
                    appvalue = 30;


                    break;
                    case "Week":
                    appvalue = 4;


                    break;
                    case "Month":
                    appvalue = 1;


                    break;


                }


            }
        });
    date6.setSelectedItem(date[0]);



    l13 = new JLabel (""+email2+" MB");
    double web1 = 0;
    l14 = new JLabel (""+web1+" WebPages");



    l16 = new JLabel (""+web2+" MB");
    double IM1 = 0;
    l17 = new JLabel (""+IM1+" IMs");



    l19 = new JLabel (""+IM2+" MB");
    double video1 = 0;
    l20 = new JLabel (""+video1+" Minutes");



    l22 = new JLabel (""+video2+" MB");
    double song1 = 0;
    l23 = new JLabel (""+song1+" MP3's");



    l25 = new JLabel (""+song2+" MB");
    double app1 = 0;
    l26 = new JLabel (""+app1+" App/Games");



    l28 = new JLabel (""+app2+" MB");
    //////////////////////////////////////////////// panel5
    panel5 = new JPanel ();                                            
    panel5.setLayout (new GridLayout(1,1));
    panel5.setVisible(true);
    panel5.setBackground (Color.white);
    solu1 = new JLabel ("WE THINK YOUR MONTHLY DATA USAGE WILL BE:");
    solu1.setForeground (Color.red);
    solu1.setFont (new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,20));
    double total = 0;
    total2 = new JLabel ((email2 + web2 + IM2 + video2 + song2 + app2) + "MB");
    total2.setForeground (Color.red);
    total2.setFont (new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,20));
    /////////////////////////////////////////// panel6
    panel6 = new JPanel ();
    panel6.setLayout (new GridLayout (1,1));
    panel6.setVisible (true);
    panel6.setBackground (Color.white);
    Usage = new JLabel ("Usage per unit");
    Usage.setForeground (Color.red);
    Estimated = new JLabel ("     Estimated total");
    Estimated.setForeground (Color.red);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////// panel7
    panel7 = new JPanel ();
    panel7.setLayout (new GridLayout (1,1));
    panel7.setVisible (true);
    panel7.setBackground (Color.white);
    solu2 = new JLabel ("Data usage varies by device and other factors and the");
    solu2.setForeground (Color.black);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////// Implements
    Container container = getContentPane ();
    container.setLayout (null);      //changed
    container.setBackground (Color.white);


    container.add (panel1).setBounds (0,0,1000,120);        //panel1
    panel1.add (title).setSize(500,500);


    container.add (panel2).setBounds (0,100,1000,120);      //panel2
    panel2.add (stitle);


    container.add (panel3).setBounds (0,220,1000,100);      //panel3
    panel3.add (l3);
    panel3.add (devicelist);
    panel3.add (l4);


    container.add (panel4).setBounds (0,340,1000,150);      //panel4
    Email.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());
    Web.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());
    IM.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());
    Video.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());
    Song.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());
    App_G.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());


    panel4.add (l5);
    panel4.add (Email);
    panel4.add (l11);
    panel4.add (date1);
    panel4.add (l12);
    panel4.add (l13);
    panel4.add (l6);
    panel4.add (Web);
    panel4.add (l14);
    panel4.add (date2);
    panel4.add (l15);
    panel4.add (l16);
    panel4.add (l7);
    panel4.add (IM);
    panel4.add (l17);
    panel4.add (date3);
    panel4.add (l18);
    panel4.add (l19);
    panel4.add (l8);
    panel4.add (Video);
    panel4.add (l20);
    panel4.add (date4);
    panel4.add (l21);
    panel4.add (l22);
    panel4.add (l9);
    panel4.add (Song);
    panel4.add (l23);
    panel4.add (date5);
    panel4.add (l24);
    panel4.add (l25);
    panel4.add (l10);
    panel4.add (App_G);
    panel4.add (l26);
    panel4.add (date6);
    panel4.add (l27);
    panel4.add (l28);
    container.add (panel5).setBounds (210,540,1000,50);    // panel5
    panel5.add (solu1);
    panel5.add (total2);
    container.add (panel6).setBounds (670,220,200,220);      // panel6
    panel6.add (Usage);
    panel6.add (Estimated);


    container.add (panel7).setBounds (210,580,530,50);    // panel7
    panel7.add (solu2);


    Email.setOpaque(false);
    Web.setOpaque(false);
    IM.setOpaque(false); 
    Video.setOpaque(false); 
    Song.setOpaque(false);
    App_G.setOpaque(false); 
    setVisible (true);




}


public static void main (String[] args)
{
    MonthlyData application = new MonthlyData ();
}

public class SliderHandler implements ChangeListener
{
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource().equals(Email))
        {
            l11.setText(""+Email.getValue());


            email2= (Email.getValue() * emailmb)*emailvalue;
            l13.setText(email2 + "MB");
        }
        if (e.getSource().equals(Web))
        {


            l14.setText(""+Web.getValue());
            web2 = (Web.getValue() * webmb) * webvalue;
            l16.setText(web2 + "MB");


        }


        if (e.getSource().equals(IM))
        {
            l17.setText(""+IM.getValue());
            IM2 = (IM.getValue() * immb) * IMvalue;
            l19.setText(IM2 + "MB");


        }




        if (e.getSource().equals(Video))
        {
            l20.setText(""+Video.getValue());
            video2 = (Video.getValue() * videomb) * videovalue;
            l22.setText(video2 + "MB");



        }



        if (e.getSource().equals(Song))
        {
            l23.setText(""+Song.getValue());
            song2 = (Song.getValue() * songmb) * songvalue;
            l25.setText(song2 + "MB");



        }


        if (e.getSource().equals(App_G))
        {
            l26.setText(""+App_G.getValue());
            app2 = (App_G.getValue() * appmb) * appvalue;
            l28.setText(app2 + "MB");




        }


    }
}


public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);


}
```

}

Comment: Can you please point out the lines where the error has occured? It feels quite stupid to read the whole lengthy code.

Comment: Try to provide relevant code part only

Comment: Provide the stacktrace, and it wouldn't hurt to rename your variables so they have meaningful names.

Comment: Its for the string "d" right after devicelist.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

Comment: Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: I bolded the code thats getting the error. Also at home i had JDK 7. Im not sure what they have here at school.

Comment: @Sunny use java -version in a console

Comment: So apparently the problem is that switch only works in jdk 7

Comment: you owe my a new scroll wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using string in switch statement which is availabe only in java 7.Check your jdk version